# Using decltype to write copy and move functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, move-semantics, decltype

My code has a couple instances where functions react only slightly differently when encountering a T&& or const T&, however the functions themselves are quite long (note that T  is just some object type).  For instance:

```
void push_back(const T& newt){
    /* code block X */
    new (ptr) T(newt);
    /* code block Y */
}

void push_back(T&& newt){
    /* code block X */
    new (ptr) T(std::move(newt));
    /* code block Y */
}
```

is it possible to write something along the lines of this pseudo-code:

```
template<typename S>
void push_back(S newt){
    /* code block X */
#if decltype(newt)==T&&
    new (ptr) T(std::move(newt));
#else
    new (ptr) T(newt);
#endif
    /* code block Y */
}
```

Or is there a better way to write nearly identical move and copy functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::forward()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) in the `T&&` function and discard the `const T&` function:

```
template <typename T>
void push_back(T&& newt){
    /* code block X */
    new (ptr) typename std::remove_reference<T>::type(std::forward<T>(newt));
    /* code block Y */
}
```

`std::forward()` will pass on `newt` exactly as it was passed to `push_back()`. Resulting in:

- the copy constructor of `T` being used if `push_back()` is passed an lvalue, or
- the move constructor of `T` being used if `push_back()` is passed an rvalue.

See online demo at http://ideone.com/HjOrap .

Note that this is correct if `push_back()` is a free standing function or a member function of non-template class. If it is a template class member function then the function itself must accept a template type in addition to the class template type as this behaviour depends upon `T` being a deduced type.

See [Universal References](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) by Scott Meyers.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you mean.  While this is fine for doing something like {string t="hi"; push_back(std::move(t));}, this won't compile if you try doing {string t="hi"; push_back(t);}; the compiler gives some weird error.  The idea is to invoke the copy constructor or move constructor given different inputs.

Comment: this is the code that won't compile: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7yGmb99B5encmVuREx3eUVXUEE/edit (btw, is there a better way to post code?)

Comment: @Aggieboy, a version of your code that _compiles_ but has a runtime error: http://ideone.com/BrB6gK You might want to post another question for the runtime error, I am unsure and don't have much experience with placement `new`.

Comment: What about a `std::remove_cv` in addition to the `std::remove_reference`, or is this unneccessary?